# How to ensure that my job is launched through launchd and not directly?

Tags: macos, daemon, launchd, launchctl

I have a program and I want to ensure that it has been launched only by launchd (as a daemon) & it should terminate if the user launches it directly (double-click on Finder, terminal). Is there a nifty way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're the one setting up the launchd plist that specifies how to launch your program, you could just add an [`EnvironmentVariables`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html) entry to that plist with your own key (e.g. "I_CAME_FROM_LAUNCHD"), then have your program check for the presence of that environment variable using `getenv` (or `NSProcessInfo`, for Objective-C). If the program launches from the Finder, that variable won't be there, and you can terminate your program.